# async exec in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec, python-asyncio

I'd like to call exec in an async function and do something like the following code (which is not valid):

```
import asyncio

async def f():
    await exec('x = 1\n' 'await asyncio.sleep(x)')
```

More precisely, I'd like to be able to wait for a future inside the code that runs in exec.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: `await eval('asyncio.sleep(1))`

Comment: I put x=1 on purpose because I really have to call exec and not eval.

Comment: How about this? `await eval('asyncio.sleep(x)', globals(), {'x': 1})`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> **Note:** F-strings are only supported in python 3.6+. For older versions, use `%s`, `.format()` or the classic `+` concatenation.

```py
async def aexec(code):
    # Make an async function with the code and `exec` it
    exec(
        f'async def __ex(): ' +
        ''.join(f'\n {l}' for l in code.split('\n'))
    )

    # Get `__ex` from local variables, call it and return the result
    return await locals()['__ex']()
```

---

#### Known issues:

- If you use new lines in a string (triple quotes), it will mess up the formatting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See:  [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks.

Comment: I try to explain: if you have awaitable code you use instead of `eval`/`exec` `execute()` function. Execute function compile input string and create awaitable function `__ex` with all your code inside. After creating function it return function call to `__ex()` but since function not created directly, he use locals() instead to get function and make call with await.

The only one thing is missed as I think, is using globals/locals what you may optionally add to eval/exec.

Comment: @XCanG Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Yours problem is that you are trying to await to `None` object- `exec` ignores the return value from its code, and always returns `None`.
If you want to execute and await to the result you should use `eval`- `eval` returns the value of the given expression.

Your's code should look like this:

```
import asyncio

async def f():
    exec('x = 1')
    await eval('asyncio.sleep(x)')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(f())
loop.close()
```

Comment: I wanted to do it without parsing the string in order to split "x = 1" and "asyncio.sleep(x)"

Answer (score 3):

This is based off @YouTwitFace's answer, but keeps globals unchanged, handles locals better and passes kwargs. Note multi-line strings still won't keep their formatting. Perhaps you want [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.cleandoc)?

```
async def aexec(code, **kwargs):
    # Don't clutter locals
    locs = {}
    # Restore globals later
    globs = globals().copy()
    args = ", ".join(list(kwargs.keys()))
    exec(f"async def func({args}):\n    " + code.replace("\n", "\n    "), {}, locs)
    # Don't expect it to return from the coro.
    result = await locs["func"](**kwargs)
    try:
        globals().clear()
        # Inconsistent state
    finally:
        globals().update(**globs)
    return result
```

It starts by saving the locals. It declares the function, but with a restricted local namespace so it doesn't touch the stuff declared in the aexec helper. The function is named `func` and we access the `locs` dict, containing the result of the exec's locals. The `locs["func"]` is what we want to execute, so we call it with `**kwargs` from aexec invocation, which moves these args into the local namespace. Then we await this and store it as `result`. Finally, we restore locals and return the result.

> **Warning:**
>
> Do not use this if there is any multi-threaded code touching global
>   variables.
>   Go for @YouTwitFace's answer which is simpler and thread-safe, or remove the globals save/restore code

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the suggestions. I figured out that this can be done with greenlets along async, since greenlets allow performing "top level await":

```
import greenlet
import asyncio

class GreenAwait:
    def __init__(self, child):
        self.current = greenlet.getcurrent()
        self.value = None
        self.child = child

    def __call__(self, future):
        self.value = future
        self.current.switch()

    def __iter__(self):
        while self.value is not None:
            yield self.value
            self.value = None
            self.child.switch()

def gexec(code):
    child = greenlet.greenlet(exec)
    gawait = GreenAwait(child)
    child.switch(code, {'gawait': gawait})
    yield from gawait

async def aexec(code):
    green = greenlet.greenlet(gexec)
    gen = green.switch(code)
    for future in gen:
        await future

# modified asyncio example from Python docs
CODE = ('import asyncio\n'
        'import datetime\n'

        'async def display_date():\n'
        '    for i in range(5):\n'
        '        print(datetime.datetime.now())\n'
        '        await asyncio.sleep(1)\n')

def loop():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(aexec(CODE + 'gawait(display_date())'))
    loop.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed as well. Nice to know that others have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more robust way using the builtin `ast` module:

```py
import ast

async def async_exec(stmts, env=None):
    parsed_stmts = ast.parse(stmts)

    fn_name = "_async_exec_f"

    fn = f"async def {fn_name}(): pass"
    parsed_fn = ast.parse(fn)

    for node in parsed_stmts.body:
        ast.increment_lineno(node)

    parsed_fn.body[0].body = parsed_stmts.body
    exec(compile(parsed_fn, filename="<ast>", mode="exec"), env)

    return await eval(f"{fn_name}()", env)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [module](https://pypi.org/project/meval/) using **AST** to do stuff. This means that mutli-line strings will work perfectly and line-numbers will match the original statements. Also, if anything is an expression, it is returned (as a list if there are multiple, otherwise as just an element)

I made this module (check the revision history of this answer for more details on the inner workings). I use it [here](https://github.com/friendly-telegram/friendly-telegram/blob/master/friendly-telegram/modules/python.py)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this function:

```
import asyncio
async def async_exec(code):
    t = [None]
    exec('async def _async_exec():\n return {}\nt[0] = asyncio.ensure_future(_async_exec())'.format(code))
    return await t[0]
```

Here is a code example that can directly run. (It works for Python 3.6.8)

```
import asyncio
async def async_exec(code):
    t = [None]
    exec('async def _async_exec():\n return {}\nt[0] = asyncio.ensure_future(_async_exec())'.format(code))
    return await t[0]

async def p(s):
    await asyncio.sleep(s)
    return s


async def main():
    print(await async_exec('await p(0.1) / await p(0.2)'))


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

I try to explain it, define an async function in exec.  Inside the async function, run the code you want.  But exec doesn't have return value, use t[0] to store an asyncio future, await the future outside of exec to get the return value.

Answer (score 0):

As of Python 3.8, you can `compile()` the code with the flag [`ast.PyCF_ALLOW_TOP_LEVEL_AWAIT`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/ast.html#ast.PyCF_ALLOW_TOP_LEVEL_AWAIT) and `eval` it to get a coroutine back, which you can then `await`. Despite using `eval`, multiple statements are supported.

Here is a minimal example of how to do this:

```py
import ast
import asyncio

async def main() -> None:
    code = compile(
        "x = 1\n"
        "await asyncio.sleep(0.1)\n"
        "print('done!')\n",
        "<string>",
        "exec",
        flags=ast.PyCF_ALLOW_TOP_LEVEL_AWAIT,
    )
    coroutine: Awaitable | None = eval(code)
    if coroutine is not None:
        await coroutine

asyncio.run(main())
```

When there are no `await` statements, `eval()` runs the code immediately then returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the different answers, the only thing that I missed was the local variables (couldn't make them be global).

Here is what I did :

```py
async def async_eval_or_exec(message, vars):
    # Translating the command into a function
    # The function returns the main result AND the local variables to make them accessible outside

    if message.count("\n"):
        function = "async def __execute__():\n    " + message.replace("\n", "    ") + "\n    return None, locals()\n"
    else:
        function = "async def __execute__():\n    return " + message + ", locals()\n"

    # The execution - get the result of 
    try:
        exec(function, vars, vars)
        result = await vars["__execute__"] ()
        if result[ 0 ] is not None:
            return result[ 0 ]
        vars.update(result[ 1 ]) # forces the local variables (inside __execute__) to be global
    except SyntaxError: # for commands like "import os"
        exec(message, vars, vars)
```

And then, I can run :

```py
>>> vars = {}
>>> await async_eval_or_exec('x = 1', vars)
>>> await async_eval_or_exec('await asyncio.sleep(x)', vars)
>>> await async_eval_or_exec('print(x)', vars)
1
>>>
```

It can be useful if you create an async interpreter (to not lose objects you create inside the **execute** function).

I think it is better than using the "global" command every time you create a variable.